# Does it take 200L of water to make a latte?

Tags: nutrition, water

I just saw this [Youtube clip](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-nekqKEsbdU) that claims it takes 200L of water to make a latte. Is that true?

Comment: "Using water" is one of those weird claims.  Water is a molecule that is very strong and likes to be what it is.  Very rarely in systems that we think of was "using water" does water actually become anything other than water.  Usually it just moves around or becomes more or less polluted.  But for instance, "low flow toilets" just increase the waste/water ratio in sewage.  Most of the water in coffee growth goes back to the air.  I'm commenting instead of answering because the entire premise is so misleading that it's hard to even know where to start.

Comment: I agree with Russell... Unless one of the steps to make latte involves [hydrolysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrolysis), no water is being "used"; it just goes somewhere else and eventually finds its way back into the rivers/oceans.

Comment: While voting Russells comment up, there might be problems in the kind water is used. If you need to transport it for far ways, and if it evaporates easily, causing soil erosion in an area, where other plants would use less water, and the water would stay there for a longer time ... - In economical models, the money should force the resources to be used in a reasonable way, but ecological costs are often paid by the society and afterwards, and not put into the prices. I don't think it's an easy question in either way.

Comment: @Russel: Using water is just as weird as producing carbon pollution. Just because no new carbon gets created doesn't mean that carbon pollution isn't an issue. The world fresh water supply is decreasing.

Comment: @Russell, @Jason: Water is used at least temporarily. So I guess measuring in litres isn't very accurate. There probably is a more accurate measure

Comment: To be more accurate (if not more international), "latte" refers to milk. It takes no water to make a glass of latte. "Cafe latte", on the other hand...

Comment: @christian: it is different in that the carbon in question is typically "locked" and has been that ways for many millions of years. It's re-uptake is also on a much larger scale and therefore the ratios in the cycle are significantly different. The water cycle is much shorter and balanced.

Comment: @Horatio: The water cycle isn't balanced. The world freshwater reverses are going down. http://www.digitaljournal.com/article/301586

Comment: What does that have to do with carbon realease?

Comment: Sheesh folks...I think you can assume for purposes of this question that the word "take" refers to ordinary consumption mechanisms like irrigation, evaporation, or water going down the drain or into the latte.

Comment: Some of the commenters here don't have to pay for water usage like the rest of us apparently. Or "take" is a synonyms of "destroy".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

http://www.marcgunther.com/2009/02/25/the-anatomy-of-a-latte/
Provides a writeup on the number. In this case of the water seems to come from tropical rainstorms that rain on coffee fields and the issue isn't that big.

> Here’s the breakdown, by liters, of the water needed to make that latte:
>
> 0.1 for the water itself
> 2.5 to make the plastic lid
> 5.5 to make the paper cup and sleeve
> 7.5 to grow the sugar
> 49.5 to feed the cows that make the milk
> 143 to grow the coffee
>
> That adds up to more than 200 liters of water to make a latte.

Comment: Fails to take into account the 100 gallons used to wash the cows' udders, the 500 gallons used to cool the factory that makes the lids and cups, etc.